# How to check for multiple values in dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict1 = {'galaxy': 5, 'apple': 6, 'nokia': 5}
```

Is there is a way to show the keys in a dict with the same values in a dict?

```
target_value = 5
new_dict = {}

for key, value in dict1:
    if value == target_value:
        new_dict[key] = value
```

desired output:

```
dict1 = {'galaxy':5, 'nokia':5}
```

Comment: Of course, but you'll have to *write some code*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can u give me a hint, been stuck for an hour.

Comment: Stuck on *what*, exactly? Where's the [mcve]? Where's *your effort?* Learn [ask].

Comment: @jonsharpe its part of a big code that i have but im just asking a concept here. Let me see if i can edit the OP with a sample code

Comment: Don't name your variable _dict_, it's override the _dict_ built in type.

Comment: @OhadEytan i have updated the OP

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @OhadEytan basically, I want all the keys that have the same value in a dict. If there is only one key with one value in that dict, its fine. My desired output is like new_dict1 = {'galaxy':5, 'nokia'5}

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something like that:

```
>>> d = {'galaxy': 5, 'apple': 6, 'nokia': 5}
>>> { k:v for k,v in d.items() if v==5 }
{'nokia': 5, 'galaxy': 5}
```

Comment: thank you. ive seen this before. but there isnt a simpler way right?

Comment: That depends on what you consider simple.

Comment: How about `dict(kv for kv in dict1.items() if kv[1] == 5)`? There are fewer lookups which may make it modestly faster.

Comment: I changed my answer according to the edited question.

Comment: @OhadEytan thank you but wouldnt my code in the OP work? it has been edited

Comment: @OhadEytan i tried running that code, but im getting a ValueError at for key,v in dict1:

Comment: @coder otherwise the original `dict1` doesn't changed

Comment: @tdelaney Actually, I timed that with a big dict. Solution which Ohad Eytan gave turns out to be marginally faster. But even if it were not, it looks better. Which shows why premature optimization is the root of all evil ;)